# Cannot read property 'engine' of undefined - Webpack React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try to learn React.JS, by typing "webpack"  command, i found this error :

> Hash: 04008667f996e5267ae1 Version: webpack 1.14.0 Time: 580ms
>       + 2 hidden modules
>
> ERROR in ./public/assets/react-source/catalog-app.js Module build
>   failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'engine' of undefined
>       at load (/var/www/html/web/node_modules/transform/index.js:33:18)
>       at Object.transform (/var/www/html/web/node_modules/transform/index.js:19:3)
>
> ERROR in ./public/assets/react-source/catalog-custom-item-app.js
>   Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'engine' of
>   undefined
>       at load (/var/www/html/web/node_modules/transform/index.js:33:18)
>       at Object.transform (/var/www/html/web/node_modules/transform/index.js:19:3)

Anyone can help pls ?
Already installed react-engine. My react app running well before.

Comment: can you share your package.json content ?

Comment: @Ash

check this : https://jsfiddle.net/uwz9ojfu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by typing this command :

```
npm install transform
```

then

```
npm install
```